# Pheanstalk queueng list reserve PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

Hi All i am having trouble on my pheanstalk sorry this is my first time of using this. My project involves a one save of 5000 entries the php when i work on gets 502 because of the traffic request.So my solution to these is to use a pheanstalk on the process here is my code below which is okay. I have installed the beanstalk on the server.

```
    require("vendor/autoload.php");
use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');   

#producer
$put = $pheanstalk->useTube("ashimatube".date("His"))
->put(json_encode(array("test"=>date("Yhs"))));

#worker
$job = $pheanstalk->watch("ashimatube".date("His"))
->ignore("default")->reserve();
```

Comment: Where did you keep Pheanstalk PHP client? And are you getting any error/warnings?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

## Beanstalk

**Beanstalk** used in Facebook developed by **Philotic**, Inc to improves the response time for the Causes on the Facebook application (with over 10 million users). Beanstalk decreased the average response time for the most common pages to a tiny fraction of the original, significantly improving the user experience.

Here is the sample for Codeigniter

1. Download **Pheastalk** from [here](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk).

***Pheastalk** is a PHP client for beanstalkd queue.*

2. Add **Pheanstalk** folder inside `application/libraries`.
3. Create `pheanstalk.php` under `application/config`.
4. Add the following code.

   ```
   <?php

     if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
       exit('No direct script access allowed');

      $config['ip'] = '192.168.0.2'; // Example IP, Enter your IP
      $config['port'] = 11300;
   ```
5. Create Pheanstalk.php (P is in caps) under `application/libraries`.
6. Add the following code.

   ```
    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
      exit('No direct script access allowed');

    /** Pheanstalk root directory */
    if (!defined('PHEANSTALK_ROOT')) 
    {
         define('PHEANSTALK_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
         require(PHEANSTALK_ROOT . 'pheanstalk/pheanstalk_init.php');
    }

    class Pheanstalk extends Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk 
    {

       public function __construct($params) 
       {
           parent::__construct($params['ip'], $params['port']);
       }
    }
   ```
7. Create a controller like this.

   ```
    Class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {

     public function index() 
     {
       $this->load->library('pheanstalk');
       var_dump($this->pheanstalk->listTubes());
       $this->pheanstalk->useTube('testtube')->put("job payload goes here\n");

       $job = $this->pheanstalk
               ->watch('testtube')
               ->ignore('default')
               ->reserve();

       echo $job->getData();

       $this->pheanstalk->delete($job);
   } }
   ```

Just Try this way.